# Slight delay between addClass to multiple elements

Tags: jquery

OK, I've got this bit of script which adds a class name to certain elements when they become visible.

```
var t = $("#div").offset().top;

$(document).scroll(function(){
    if($(this).scrollTop() > t)
    {   
        $('.image').addClass('img-vis');
    }
});
```

There are 12 elements with class name lazy and I want a slight delay between each class addition.

Comment: "class name lazy " lazy or image?

Comment: [http://luis-almeida.github.io/unveil/](unveil) is your friend, just in case.

Comment: Sorry, classname image

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try that:

```
$('.image').each(function (i) {
    $(this).delay(i*1000).queue(function (next) {
        $(this).addClass('img-vis');
        next(); //used just to dequeue
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you mean something like this:

```
$(document).scroll(function(){
    if($(this).scrollTop() > t)
    {   
        setTimeout( addImgVis, 1000 );
    }
});

function addImgVis(){
    $('.image').addClass('img-vis');
}
```

that will add the class 1 second ( ie. 1000 milliseconds ) after it executes w/in ur scroll function.

Comment: It's gonna add the class to all the images at the same time, over and over again. Your selector is returning all the images with the class = image.